# Are number of rows fetched in Solr restricted as data increases?

Tags: solr, cassandra, dataimporthandler

In my Cassandra database, I have a table named Person having about 10,00,000 rows. I have integrated Solr and Cassandra.

When I try to index data with minimum number of rows, about 100, all the rows are being indexed. However, with large number of rows, as mentioned above, I'm able to index only 10,000 rows out of all.

Is there any restriction in indexing data by solr? I tried to google it out, but couldn't find any quick answer. Or does it index with the unique values as I have many duplicate values as well? Or is it like the earlier records are being removed and updated with the latest while indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Document is the unit of information in Solr and each document *must* have a unique key.
This must be a field and will not permit any duplicate within the Solr instance.
This means that any document getting indexed with a duplicate key will overwrite past documents.
So old documents will be removed and new one inserted.

The unique key is defined in the schema.xml and by default is "id".

Comment: Thank you. There was other problem also, row limitation. I changed it.